# MediaFire Data Retention?

Tags: data-recovery, mediafire

There Data Retention Policy Is Below-
https://www.mediafire.com/policies/data_retention.php#data_retention_table

1. Can someone read this information from the link and inform me what it means when they state "These are short term logs of who accessed and downloaded content from whom’s account. We keep this for the minimum amount of time necessary to ensure resumable downloads etc".
2. Does this mean IP logs, account names, emails, etc? The description is quite vague. However, someone more experienced may know.
3. I would like to know if it’s ok to download those games and movies we all love without being sent a warning by DMCA.
4. I don’t know if this is the right place to post this question. If not, please redirect me to the right forum.
   Thank you

Comment: Does anyone know what’s being stored for 10 years. That seems outrageous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webpage says:

> MediaFire takes your privacy seriously and is not in the business of tracking you; we are in the business of helping you store, share, and access your data.

Note #1 says a log **file** is retained for **3 hours** and note #2 says that the information necessary to allow downloads to be resumed is retained **in memory** for **72 hours**.

> ... without being sent a warning by DMCA ...

Theoretically, they could see the file that they object to has been uploaded, go to court and obtain a warrant to seize the log files and obtain a 3-hour long list of downloaders.

So yes, it's ***possible*** just unlikely.

It's more likely, and useful, to go after the uploader or complain that the website doesn't check ***all*** it's uploads, but that's what a takedown request is for. A large website can't watch everything and there are no simple means to catch everything.

YouTube has a system in place where content creators can upload samples which are then tested against uploads. On YouTube, you get a "strike" for a match, three strikes and you'll be banned from uploading for a period of time. It is also possible to dispute the complaint, I've done that a few times and been successful since the matching algorithms are not perfect and the other party makes mistakes sometimes; I make certain that **I** don't make such a mistake and get banned.

Comment: Are ip adresses permanently stored forever or is that part of the log files that get deleted.

Comment: Also, thanks for the help bro.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that is good for me . However, ppl who do worse on these sites like terroritsts and criminals would be hard to catch if they delete log mad quick.. MediaFire is something else 

Comment: ONE MORE THING, what’s being stored for 10 years. That’s so long.

Comment: Record required for legal compliance?